# java.lang.IllegalStateException on AddingView to ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

im trying to addView's and Remove View's Depending on my Need From my ListView Adapter, by Calling :

```
 holder.wrapper.removeView(holder.PimageView);
 holder.wrapper.removeView(holder.theMessage);
```

and

```
 holder.wrapper.addView(holder.PimageView);
```

depending on my need, when convertView is null (First time they load) it works find, but when i refresh that (ConvertView not null) im getting this error:

```
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019): Process: com.lifemate.lmmessenger, PID:  
 2019
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The  
 specified 
 child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):    at 
 android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):    at 
 android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):    at 
 android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3360)
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):    at 
 android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):    at 
 com.lifemate.lmmessenger.listviewengine.ChatAdapter.getView(ChatAdapter.java:249)
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):    at 
 android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240)
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):    at 
 android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):    at 
 android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:725)
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):    at 
 android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1611)
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):    at 
 android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):    at 
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):    at 
 android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
 07-05 14:00:36.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):    at  
 android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
```

and by the way the last row says RelativeLayout.onLayout, but i my xml is FrameLayout with a LinearLayout child, is this normal?

this is my code:

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
   if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_discuss, null);
        this.convertview=convertView;



    System.out.println("ConverView null");

    holder.PimageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.PimageView);
    holder.wrapper = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
    holder.theMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
    holder.theName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MSGname);
    holder.theImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.MSGimage);
    holder.lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) holder.theName.getLayoutParams();

 holder.paramsleft = new  FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.LEFT);

 holder.paramsright = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.RIGHT);


    convertView.setTag(holder);

   }else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   String theType="Known";

if(holder.badge!=null){
    holder.badge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.badge.invalidate();
    holder.badge=null;
 }

    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);   
    String imagenamer= 
 (mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("username")).split("\\@"))[0];
    int isright= Integer.valueOf(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("isright")));
    holder.wrapper.removeView(holder.PimageView);
    holder.wrapper.removeView(holder.theMessage);
    // here both DependantViews are removed

  //Condition 1 :

  holder.wrapper.addView(holder.PimageView);

  //Condition 2 : 

  holder.wrapper.addView(holder.theMessage);
```

these methods are where Error happenes, i have tried View.GONE, and View.VISIBLE, but after scrolling listview gets mixed up and leaves the layout Space Reserved to the PImageView empty when its supposed to be GONE, like when you call View,INVISIBLE.

here is my XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<FrameLayout 
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/MSGname"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="TextView"
       />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/MSGimage"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="right"

      />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/PimageView"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the holder:

```
   if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_discuss, null);
        this.convertview=convertView;



    System.out.println("ConverView null");

    holder.PimageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.PimageView);
    holder.wrapper = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
    holder.theMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
    holder.theName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MSGname);
    holder.theImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.MSGimage);
    holder.lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) holder.theName.getLayoutParams();
    holder.paramsleft = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams
   (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.LEFT);
    holder.paramsright = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams
  (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.RIGHT);


    convertView.setTag(holder);

   }else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }
```

and the Viewholder:

```
  public static class ViewHolder {

    private TextView theMessage;

    private TextView theName;

    private LinearLayout wrapper;       

    private ImageView PimageView;

    ImageView theImage;

    ImageView theImage2;

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp;

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsleft;

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsright;

    BadgeView badge ;

    VideoView PvideoView;

  }
```

sorry if its repeated, but some body asked precisely

any help guys what is wrong? thanks alot

Comment: Where is line 249 of ChatAdapter.java?

Comment: i mentioned, its       holder.wrapper.addView(holder.theMessage);

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement the View Holder pattern, but haven't done it correctly.

Comment: What is the declaration for `ViewHolder`?

Comment: If you are going to store the LinearLayout from your inflated view, you don't need to store its children nor add them because they already belong to the LinearLayout.

Comment: in the holder you mean? can you be more precise please

Comment: I suggest that you read http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder for more information about the ViewHolder pattern.

Comment: You don't need to add the views to the holder's LinearLayout at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly implementing the ViewHolder pattern. Since the views you get with `findViewById()` are already children of a `LinearLayout`, you don't need to call `addView()` at all.

Comment: man, as i explained, i need to remove and Add the View of them upon need,i am removing both View's before adding them, my Question is why is this happening when View is removed what you think i am , a retard? :D

Comment: @user3805809 Why are you removing the views at all?

Comment: because i have a listview for my chat app, some times i need to show imageView not textView, and vice versa

Comment: @user3805809 Then you should have two different layouts rather than trying to manipulate a single layout.

Comment: hmm, thank you, can you lead me to a correct tutorial for that? because the way i figured it out was creating 2x ViewHolder and ConvertView's for them which didnt seems right

Comment: Yes, you will need two separate ViewHolder's, one for each layout. You will also need to check if the `convertView` is the correct layout before reusing it.

Comment: all right and then i guess override getViewType, right? ok thanks alot i take that as an answer

Comment: also this is a great tutorial if some one needed in this case:http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296